# position: fixed; does not base element in viewport

Tags: css

I've read in a number of places that position: fixed; should base the element in the viewport, not it's parent element, because it has been removed from normal document flow. However, as can be seen in the following code it does seem to work this way. The element with position fixed  takes it's starting point in the parent element . What gives!? Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssreset.css">
<head>
<title>TTK</title>
<style>
* {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.container {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 25px auto;
 border: 5px solid black;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
}
.positionFixed {
 width: 750px;
 height: 250px;
 border: 3px solid blue; /* why does the border not show up */
 position: fixed;
 background: red;
}
</style>
</head>]
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="positionFixed"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont get the question in the css comment, here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/7cymedo7/) The `positionFixed`is fixed at the top left, if you dont add the aspect of rblarsen's answer. Because of the fact that the positionFixed width is greater it overleaps the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont tell where the `position:fixed;` element should be, it wont know. Add some placement (top, left, right and/or bottom), and it should be positioned right.

```
.positionFixed {
    width: 750px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 3px solid blue; /* why does the border not show up */
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ok so if I don't use any placement (top, left, etc) then the element with position: fixed; will use it's parent element, not the viewport as the basis for placement.

Comment: If you dont use any placement, it will place where it is put in the code, as if it had `position:static;`

Answer (score 1):

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp